# What's the Mode of a Bivariate Poisson Distribution?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, proof, bivariate, mode

I have been looking at the bivariate Poisson distribution and I am wondering if there is close form expression for the *mode* of this distribution. I know the mode of the univariate Poisson distribution is $\lfloor \lambda\rfloor$.

Let $Y_0$, $Y_1$, and $Y_2$ be mutually stochastically independent Poisson random variables, with positive parameters $\lambda_0$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively. Then, a non-trivial bivariate Poisson distribution is the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$ where we have

$$X_1 = Y_1 + Y_0$$
$$X_2 = Y_2 + Y_0$$

with joint probability mass function

$$f(x_1, x_2) = \frac{e^{(-\lambda_0 - \lambda_1 -\lambda_2)} \lambda _0^{x_1} \left(-\lambda _2\right)^{-x_1} \lambda _2^{x_2} }{x_1! x_2!} U\left(-x_1, 1-x_1+x_2, -\frac{\lambda _1 \lambda _2}{\lambda _0}\right)$$

defined on $x_i \in {0, 1, \dots}$, and where $U(.)$ denotes the confluent hypergeometric function. Finally, let $(x_1^m, x_2^m)$ denote the bivariate mode... Now my question, is there a known derivation for establishing the modes of this distribution? That is, calculating the value of $(x_1, x_2)$ at which $f(x_1, x_2)$ is a maximum?

---

*Note, there is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/582435/13062) but the answer is numerical. Although this provides great insight into the problem and indeed a candidate result, I would very much like an analytical solution (if it is possible). I have searched about but cannot find any paper where this has been done. I am not asking someone to embark upon this for me, but I would like some advice about possible avenues of attack as the direct approach of calculating the derivatives does not seem like the way to go. Alternatively, and references that may help in a search for a solution would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: The answer you linked makes an analytic solution seem very unlikely. What's the reason that a numeric solution won't suffice? e: Would an analytic approximation to the mode do? If so, what are typical ranges for $\lambda_0, \lambda_1, \lambda_2$?

Comment: I agree an analytical solution _looks_ unlikely, however, this does not mean there is not one. Someone in the statistics community must have thought about this problem, but I can't seem to find any references. The numeric solution to this will be very expensive for what we need it for. We are likely to need tens of thousands of iterations for the parameters, the analytical solution would circumvent this. The range for the parameters for what we need this for is likely to be $\lambda_{0}, \lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2} \in [0.0, 3.0]$.

Comment: Check [this discussion](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/246496), which seems relevant. However, it is still unclear to me whether an analytical solution exists or not.

Comment: This is not for the Bivariate case unfortunately...

Comment: "there is a similar question here but the answer is numerical" No.

Comment: @Did what do you mean by "No". That my statement that the answer is numerical, or whether you can comment as to whether there is an analytical solution for the bivariate case? Thanks for your time...

Comment: What I mean is what is written in my first comment: that  the answer "there" is not "numerical".

Comment: Sorry, I disagree, perhaps our definition of what is classed as "numerical" differs. In summary, call it what you want, but the answer "there" is not a purely analytical solution. It involves a numerical search over the parameter space. Thanks for your time...